# The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead

Tags: angular

> When i am trying to initializing "this.post" to assign into a variable it won't allow me to do that. I am using Angular 8

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  
  post: any[];
  
  
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
      http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(responce => {

          this.post = responce

      })

     }

 
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Is `responce` an array? You should log it to see the value. The error would indicate that it's an object

Comment: yes the response is in array but if i make post:object[] its still showing me error

Comment: Add an example of what the response looks like in your question. (Using type `any` with no brackets will probably fix your problem though)

Comment: i used post:object and its working now

Comment: Yes, so likely the array that you are expecting is actually wrapped inside of the object that is returned

Comment: declare the type in subscribe function: `.subscribe((responce:any[]) => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

here TypeScript is complaining about type mismatch, subscription function parameter has type object and u are assigning it to other type

[httpClient.get](https://angular.io/guide/http) function is generic means u can tell it what will be response type, if u don't provide it, it will set to object as default.

seems like u are assigning ur response to post which is type of any[]

So this will work

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
          http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(responce => {        
              this.post = responce       
          })        
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

here typescript is complaining about type mismatch response is object and u are assigning it to other type

[httpClinet.get](https://angular.io/guide/http) function is generic means u can tell it what will be response type, if u don't provide it, it will set it set to object as default

seems like u are assigning ur response to post which is type of any[]

So this will work

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
          http.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(responce => {        
              this.post = responce       
          })        
         }
```